# SQL query of two table

Tags: sql, oracle

I run a SQL command where i need to get the count of the table b

```
SELECT A.ENTITY_ID, B.ENTITY_ID
FROM structure A, equipment B 
WHERE A.STRUCTURE_NAME = B.STRUCTURE_NAME 
AND A.XXXID in ();
```

Table 1

Structure

Column A – 18 character ID (eg – asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw)

Table 2

Equipment

Column B – 27 character of which the first 18 character is the exactly the  18 character of Column A (eg – asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppooo001)

So when I put a query I get a list like

```
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppooo001
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppooo002
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppxxx001
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppeee001
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppeee001
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  - asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwpppccc002
```

What I want is just the count

```
asdfghjklzxcvbnmqw  6
```

Comment: and what is you expected result ?

Comment: Use [`COUNT(*)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm).

Comment: What i want is the count of column 2 against column 1. When i put the count      SELECT Count (*) A.ENTITY_ID, B.ENTITY_ID
FROM structure A, equipment B 
WHERE A.STRUCTURE_NAME = B.STRUCTURE_NAME 
AND A.XXXID in (); i get a error of FROM....I am new to SQL and hence need some help

Comment: You say that `structure.entity_id` is a substring of `equipment.entity_id`. But that doesn't have anything to do with the problem, as you seem to be getting the matching records by joining by `structure_name` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison using `like` or with string manipulation:

```
SELECT s.ENTITY_ID, e.ENTITY_ID
FROM structure s JOIN
     equipment e 
     ON b.STRUCTURE_NAME = SUBSTR(e.STRUCTURE_NAME, 1, 18)
WHERE s.XXXID in (. . .);
```

Notice the other changes I've made:

- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table names -- much simpler to read the query.
- The query uses proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

EDIT:

If you want the count, then use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM structure s JOIN
     equipment e 
     ON b.STRUCTURE_NAME = SUBSTR(e.STRUCTURE_NAME, 1, 18)
WHERE s.XXXID in (. . .);
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT s.ENTITY_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM structure s JOIN
     equipment e 
     ON b.STRUCTURE_NAME = SUBSTR(e.STRUCTURE_NAME, 1, 18)
WHERE s.XXXID in (. . .)
GROUP BY s.ENTITY_ID;
```

Comment: The outcome is not what i want

Comment: What i get with your query is the total as I get with my query. I then transfer to an excel and then put in a pivot table to get the result

Comment: @Lemuel . . . You should be doing the count in SQL.

Comment: When i put count i get the error that it cannot find FROM

Comment: @Lemuel . . . These queries seem syntactically correct.  Do they run in a tool with a direct connection to the database?

Comment: They run in the same database but different tables

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following answer if it is what you want

create view vTemp as
SELECT Count(A.ENTITY_ID) as countA ,A.ENTITY_ID
FROM structure A

SELECT A.countA,A.ENTITY_ID, B.ENTITY_ID
FROM vTemp A, equipment B 
WHERE A.STRUCTURE_NAME = B.STRUCTURE_NAME 
AND A.XXXID in ();

Comment: The result is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

This `SELECT A.ENTITY_ID, count(*)
FROM structure A, equipment B 
WHERE A.STRUCTURE_NAME = B.STRUCTURE_NAME 
AND A.XXXID in ()
group by a.entity;` doesn't work for you?

Comment: This is the error i Get                     ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"